# Closing a tab in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my tab to close at the end of a method call. I used window.close(). But it isnt working and I am getting a triangular yellow exclamation mark in the debugger with message that says "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it".

Can someone tell me how I can close any tab? Thanks.

Im using Chrome but I need it to work on all browsers.

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it

Comment: Is that a blanket statement or is there a way around that?

Comment: It is because of the security, you can close the window **only** if you open it.

Comment: There's no way around that. It wouldn't be a very good security measure if you could circumvent it.

Comment: since you can't close the window, a compromise I use is to navigate to a different page, such as about:blank, or some custom page of your choosing

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what you're asking. Javascript can only window.close() windows that it had created using window.open()

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close